# Excel VBA loop and get value from an array

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code to retrieve a selection then making it a array of string.

```
Dim strArgument As Variant
Dim irange As Range
Dim ricosString As Variant

Set irange = Selection
ricosString = RangeToStringArray(irange)

Dim vArray As Variant
For i = LBound(ricosString) To UBound(ricosString)
    Set vArray = ricosString(i)
```

My problem here is on the `ricosString(i)`. It is throwing an error `Subscript out of range.` Any ideas why?

Here is the code for `RangeToStringArray`

```
Public Function RangeToStringArray(theRange As Excel.Range) As String()

Dim variantValues As Variant
variantValues = theRange.Value

Dim stringValues() As String
ReDim stringValues(1 To UBound(variantValues, 1), 1 To UBound(variantValues, 2))

Dim columnCounter As Long, rowCounter As Long
For rowCounter = UBound(variantValues, 1) To 1 Step -1
   For columnCounter = UBound(variantValues, 2) To 1 Step -1
       stringValues(rowCounter, columnCounter) = CStr(variantValues(rowCounter, columnCounter))
   Next columnCounter
Next rowCounter

RangeToStringArray = stringValues
```

End Function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RangeToStringArray is 2 dimensional but you reference it as 1 dimensional
Set vArray = ricosString(i)

Also Ricostring is not an object so you should not use Set

Answer (score 0):

Regarding that `RangeToStringArray` function, I don't really see its interest: why don't you just use `ricosString  = irange`, which would be simpler and faster?

Answer (score 0):

Define your ricosString as a proper String Array:

```
Dim ricosString() As String
```

Replace your RangeToStringArray Function with a proper one:

```
Public Function RangeToStringArray(theRange As Excel.Range) As String()

Dim cell As Range
Dim values() As String
Dim i As Integer

i = 0

ReDim values(theRange.Cells.Count)

For Each cell In theRange

    values(i) = cell.Value
    i = i + 1
Next cell

RangeToStringArray = values
End Function
```

Then you can refer to the values in the array like this:

```
vArray = ricosString(i) 'without Set
```

Comment: When I changed the `RangeToStringArray` function, it is erroring on the line `For i = LBound(ricosString) To UBound(ricosString)`

Comment: Subscript out of range.

Comment: How are you looping on the array `ricosString`?

Comment: For i = LBound(ricosString) To UBound(ricosString) Step 1 | i is defined as an Integer